# DialogPreference in Full Screen Width

Tags: android

I created a custom dialog preference in my Android application, but I can not figure out how to get the dialog which is displayed to span the complete width of the display.

[image of dialog with too much space on left and right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAUzj.png)

I found many proposed solutions to get a normal Dialog in full screen mode

- [Android get full width for custom Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28513616/android-get-full-width-for-custom-dialog)
- https://gist.github.com/koocbor/88db64192638bff09aa4
- http://blog.jimbaca.com/force-dialog-to-take-up-full-screen-width/

But setting the attributes via getWindow does not work:

```
@Override
public Dialog getDialog() {

    Dialog dialog = super.getDialog();    
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    // or 
    // dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    return dialog;
}
```

And applying a full screen theme to my dialogs root element didn't do the job neither:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    [...]
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
```

Moreover I'm not able to access the onCreate Method (at least I don't know how) of the Dialog, to set the style there.

**Did anyone had the same problem and figured out a solution for this very specific issue?**

My layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/preferences_dialog_def_padding"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/preferences_dialog_def_padding">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
            android:background="@color/expandable_preference_divider"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/preferences_expandable_margin_top_bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/preferences_expandable_margin_top_bottom">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_wrapper_choose"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_wrapper_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_wrapper_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_size"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_settings_white_36dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_wrapper_choose"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/preferences_expandable_text_padding_top_bottom"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/preferences_expandable_text_padding_top_bottom"
                android:text="@string/pref_wheel_circumference_choose"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/etrto_hint"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/etrto"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/manufacturer"/>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:background="@color/expandable_preference_divider"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/preference_category_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/preferences_expandable_margin_top_bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/preferences_expandable_margin_top_bottom">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/icon_wrapper_manual"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_wrapper_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_wrapper_size"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:gravity="center">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+android:id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/preferences_expandable_icon_size"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:cropToPadding="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_white_36dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+android:id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/icon_wrapper_manual"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/preferences_expandable_text_padding_top_bottom"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/preferences_expandable_text_padding_top_bottom"
                android:text="@string/pref_wheel_circumference_manually"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/scrollbarSize"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/preference_expandable_icon_margin"
            android:weightSum="2.5"
            >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/pref_dialog_wheelcircumference_et"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/colorFont"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                android:inputType="number"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="@string/wheel_circumference_unit"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

My custom preference class

```
public class WheelCircumferencePreference extends android.preference.DialogPreference {

private static String TAG = "CustomSwitchPreference";
private int mWheelCircumference;
public static int WHEEL_CIRCUMFERENCE_DEFAULT = 2125;

private int mDialogLayoutResId = R.layout.pref_dialog_wheelcircumference;

public WheelCircumferencePreference(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public WheelCircumferencePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle);
}

public WheelCircumferencePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.custom_preference);      
    setDialogLayoutResource(mDialogLayoutResId);
    setPositiveButtonText(getContext().getString(R.string.dialog_save));
    setNegativeButtonText(getContext().getString(R.string.dialog_cancel));
}

@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index) {
    // Default value from attribute. Fallback value is set to WHEEL_CIRCUMFERENCE_DEFAULT.
    return a.getInteger(index, WHEEL_CIRCUMFERENCE_DEFAULT);
}

@Override
protected void onSetInitialValue(boolean restorePersistedValue,
                                 Object defaultValue) {
    would load value from shared preferences
    if (restorePersistedValue) {
        mWheelCircumference = getPersistedInt(WHEEL_CIRCUMFERENCE_DEFAULT);
    } else {
        mWheelCircumference = (Integer) defaultValue;
        persistInt(mWheelCircumference);
    }
}

private EditText mWheelCircumferenceEt;


@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {

    mWheelCircumferenceEt = view.findViewById(R.id.pref_dialog_wheelcircumference_et);

    if (mWheelCircumferenceEt == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("preference dialog view must contain" +
                " a EditText with id 'pref_dialog_wheelcircumference_et'");
    }
    mWheelCircumferenceEt.setText(Integer.toString(mWheelCircumference));


    super.onBindDialogView(view);
}



@Override
public Dialog getDialog() {

    //Dialog dialog = super.getDialog();

   // WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
    //p.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    //dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(p);

    return dialog;
}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    if (positiveResult) {
        String circumferenceText = mWheelCircumferenceEt.getText().toString();

        try {
            mWheelCircumference = Integer.parseInt(circumferenceText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            NLog.e(TAG, "onDialogClosed - ", e);
            mWheelCircumference = WheelCircumferencePreference.WHEEL_CIRCUMFERENCE_DEFAULT;
        }
        persistInt(mWheelCircumference);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Actually I only want the dialog to span over the full width of the screen, not the height. If I would use a additional PreferenceFragment (as the DialogPreference is already embedded in a PreferenceFragment ) the "Dialog" (aka Fragment) would take the complete width and height (i guess).

I already implemented a solution without a DialogPrefrence, that works but is not exactly elegant

- using just a normal EditTextPreference
- adding an onPreferenceClickListener to this preference in my SettingsFragment Code

  - the ClickListener displays a simple Dialog

Example:

```
        Preference preference = findPreference(EXAMPLE_PREFRENCE);    

        if (preference != null) {

            preference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
//                    showDialog();
                }
            });
```

But as I have a lot of preferences which will display dialogs the code for the dialog creation and display bloads the SettingsFragment and makes it nearly unreadable. Therefore I thought it would be a nice solution to put the responsibility of displaying the dialog and handling the preference values to the Preference and the XML layout.

Unfortunately I got stuck with the "full width issue" mentioned above.

Note: fixed the code of getDialog as I tested different versions (also in combination with the xml theme set)

Comment: It's a ```DialogPreference```, presumably it has some kind of Dialog Theme quality that would stop you (xml doesn't tend to override them so well I find, I think it could be applied programmatically) - why not use a ```PreferenceFragment``` instead? Also, in your ```getDialog``` you're setting the _height_ to ```wrap_content``` (you want width at ```match_parent``` right?), if you're right at the start of your android journey, just read around google's docs, they're pretty good, you'll learn quickly and it will be a lot less frustrating

Comment: I edited my question to explain the issue in more detail and to show a solution that worked in the past (but which I would like to replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did find a solution for this problem:

Fetch the AlertDialog of the Preference in showDialog method

```
@Override 
protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        CustomDialogPreference.makeDialogFullScreen((AlertDialog) getDialog()); 
}
```

make it span the complete width:

```
public static void makeDialogFullScreen(AlertDialog d) {
    NLog.d(TAG, "makeDialogFullScreen enter ");
    if (d != null) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = d.getWindow().getAttributes();
        if (params != null) {
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            d.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the onResume of your dialog.

```
   // Store access variables for window and blank point
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    Point size = new Point();
    // Store dimensions of the screen in `size`
    Display display = window.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getSize(size);
    // Set the width of the dialog proportional to 75% of the screen width and height
    window.setLayout((int) (size.x * 0.75), (int) (size.y * 0.75));
    window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    // Call super onResume after sizing
```

Adjust accordingly for 100%. It works great for a dialogFragment. Haven't tried it for your case though.

Comment: As far as I know I do not have access to the underlying Dialog of the DialogPreference. Do you have any information about that matter which you can share with me?

Answer (score 0):

Wait, you're not looking for the bog-standard 'Pref settings user options appear in a dialog' thing are you? That's almost definitely already done in AndroidStudio's `add activity...> Settings Activity` in boiler plate, check it out, or look for sample settings apps

---

Anyway, I do actually have a fullscreen dialog in my app, although it purposely doesn't fill the full screen, and I actually use an activity with some fragments now instead.

Personally I think this is what your problem is, I remember having this exact issue when I first needed a dialog like this. You should just use activities and have up navigation (if you want a full screen "popup" type thing you could use the Navigation pattern that makes the home/up button an 'X' instead of a '<');

Or anything else, you don't need to have a dialog explicitly, and if you do then extend activity or dialog and get what you want.

Here's my activity stuff in case it's any use

my theme:

```
  <style name="AppTheme.FullScreenDialog"
                  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

my onCreate gist:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    ...
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getConcreteContentView());
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setUpUIComponents();
    ...
}
```

my general layout gist:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:paddingTop="6dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_security_word"
        android:paddingEnd="18dp"
        android:paddingStart="18dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_security"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_recycler"
        android:minHeight="150dp"
        android:paddingEnd="18dp"
        android:paddingStart="18dp"

        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/security_container"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Bon Chance!